# Call web service even if ios app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In my application I need to log user status every 15 minutes. Is it possible if the app is in background (not killed)??

Currently I enables the Background location update. But how to call in each and every 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

While other answers are correct about background fetch, there is also another background option called **VoIP**, which apps like Skype use. In this case OS will wake up your application more frequently (even every **10 minutes** if I remember correctly) and you can keep pinging your server in background. The obvious down side is that your app must have Voice over IP functionality, otherwise it would get rejected on the App Store.

All you need to do is add call `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` method and have `voip` enabled in background capabilities.

*Just adding this for the sake of completion.*

Comment: Why voip feature keep pinging server every 10 minutes? I don't have much knowledge of voip.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Background Fetch capabilities added in iOS7 and beyond:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html  (Search for background fetch)

You won't be able to control the interval to exactly 15 minutes but you will find that this mechanism is the closest Apple will allow.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to perform network calls at clearly specified intervals when your app is in background mode. You can tell your app to use *background fetches*

[This article](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) gives a great overview on the capabilities that you can do with this API. Basically it allows you to tell iOS that your app wants to perform networking calls in the background, however you can't exactly control when and how often iOS the network calls are going to be performed. iOS will schedule your network calls for you, and depending on how your app is used it will adopt the frequency with which it performs the requests. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW76).